# I am having trouble uploading an image in Gutenberg, can I upload it otherwise to the media library?

Tags: media, files

I am having trouble uploading an image in [Gutenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg) (there is "**infinite loading**", without error, when I try to upload and eventually no image gets uploaded to the media library).

Can I upload it otherwise to the media library and then just pull it with Gutenberg?

I didn't find where to upload images in `admin/config/media/file-system`.

Comment: Are there web browser console errors?

Comment: I didn't check because even if there were I wouldn't dare to try to debug (I am not a JavaScript expert), anyway, I have deleted Gutenberg after coming across several "bugs".